# Not able to parse json response by api in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse json in php for the response by url:

https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&titles=Ladakh

Fot parsing, I have written code:

```
    <?php

$json_string =    file_get_contents("https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&titles=Ladakh");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$parsed_data = $parsed_json['batchcomplete']['query']['pages']['18687']['revisions'];

foreach($parsed_data as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['*'];

}

        ?>
```

It prints nothing other than warning:

**Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Am I missing something here?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you need to pass the format parameter like so:

```
format=json
```

while you are passing it like format=jsonfm which gives you [image]

YOUR URL should be:
https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Ladakh

**UPDATE**

Just a bit wrong with your code you need to use:

```
$parsed_data = $parsed_json['query']['pages']['18687']['revisions'];
```

instead of `$parsed_data = $parsed_json['batchcomplete']['query']['pages']['18687']['revisions'];`

as your JSON decoded array is something like so:

```
Array
(
    [batchcomplete] => 
    [query] => Array
        (
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [18687] => Array
                        (
                            [pageid] => 18687
                            [ns] => 0
                            [title] => Ladakh
                            [revisions] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
```

You can yourself check your data using the following lines:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($parsed_json);
die;
```

Comment: Where do I pass that?

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal Good one.. :)

Comment: Now I am getting additional errors:  Illegal string offset for  'pages', 'query', '0', '16867'

Comment: @DKR if you are getting errors then try doing a `print_r()` of the decoded array .. You might be using illegal indexes.

Comment: I changed echo statement to this: print_r( $value['*']); But it has no effect in errors

Comment: Okay. this worked. but I lost format of data. Is there any way I can restore format?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141968/discussion-between-shakti-phartiyal-and-dkr).

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is that you are accessing this 
`$parsed_json['batchcomplete']['query']['pages']['18687']['revisions']` in which `$parsed_json['batchcomplete']` is not an array its `string`

**Required changes:**

1. instead loop over `$parsed_json['query']['pages']['18687']['revisions']`.
2. change format in URL `format=json`

Try this hope it will work fine...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$json_string = file_get_contents("https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Ladakh");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$parsed_data = $parsed_json['query']['pages']['18687']['revisions'];

foreach ($parsed_data as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value['*'];
}
```